# How to remove a forked project in Gitlab

Tags: github, gitlab

I forked a project to a group. But there is no option to delete that forked project. I saw `danger zone` in Github. Is there any option available to delete forked project from Gitlab?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, check wheter you have `master` role in the repository/Group. `Developer` or any other role cannot delete the project/forked project.

If you are `master` then

- Go to settings
- Go to Advanced settings.
- Click on remove project.
- Type the project name and click `confirm`

Answer (score 30):

login with `master` role in the repository.

go to forked project. then from left panel, go to `Settings => General`.

like this:

[image]

click the `Expand` from `Advance settings` panel.

[image]

go to bottom page and click `Remove project`.

[image]

then type your `projectName` and click `Confirm`.

[image]

I hope is useful.

Answer (score 2):

As per the above response, you'll not be able to fork again for about a week as the name is already taken, by the pending removed fork.

This is frustrating, and sometimes unaffordable. 
Here is what you can do from settings:

1) change the deferred removal project name

[image: changing the project name]

2) press Save Changes (ignroing potential error messages)

3) expand advanced and now rename the path as well

[image: Changing the project path]

4) try to fork again; now it worked